# Python: List Nested Dictionary to pandas DataFrame Issue

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe, nested

I am struggling with some simple from_dict conversion. I have a list nested dictionaries in dictionary as below. (quite confusing to me as well)

```
dict_total = {'Jane' : {'a1' : [1.1,1.3,1.4,1.9],
                        'a2' : [3.1,2.4,2.3,1.2],
                        'a3' : [4.3,2.3,1.5,5.3],
                        'st' : ['d','dc','sc','sc']},
              'Mark' : {'a1' : [3.1,2.3,1.3,1.9],
                        'a2' : [1.2,2.3,9.3,1.2],
                        'a3' : [1.1,5.5,1.2,5.3],
                        'st' : ['cs','s','wc','cd']}
             }
```

Above is just simple example, but my original contains more then 20000+ keys in dict_total. I want to convert this dictionary to dataframe (hopefully on loops) like below.

```
df_total = 

         a1     a2      a3      st
Jane     1.1    3.1     4.3     d
Jane     1.3    2.4     2.3     dc
Jane     1.4    2.3     1.5     sc
Jane     1.9    1.2     5.3     sc
Mark     3.1    1.2     1.1     cs
Mark     2.3    2.3     5.5     sc
Mark     1.3    9.3     1.2     wc
Mark     1.9    1.2     5.3     cd
```

As you can see the keys for dict_total would be the index of dataframe, and each keys for "Jane" and "Mark" will be the column name, and lists for values.

Hope there is a pythonic way to solve this. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think need [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) with dict comprehension, last remove first level by [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df_total = (pd.concat({k: pd.DataFrame(v) for k, v in dict_total.items()})
             .reset_index(level=1, drop=True))
print (df_total)
       a1   a2   a3  st
Jane  1.1  3.1  4.3   d
Jane  1.3  2.4  2.3  dc
Jane  1.4  2.3  1.5  sc
Jane  1.9  1.2  5.3  sc
Mark  3.1  1.2  1.1  cs
Mark  2.3  2.3  5.5   s
Mark  1.3  9.3  1.2  wc
Mark  1.9  1.2  5.3  cd
```

Comment: Thank you! One curiosity.
Is it possible to change from DataFrame like df above to my origianal dict_total?

Comment: Umm I think my question was confusing.
I have tried to use " df_total.to_dict()  " in order to go back to my original dict_total format, but it did not work. Do you know why?

Comment: @Kang - I understand what you need, but in my opinion there is no pythonic solution for it. The most pythonic are [dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1373164)